# How to prove this assigns clause, part 2?

Tags: frama-c

I can't think of any idea to get `foo`'s assigns clause to be proved.  I tried `assigns var;` since `foo()` indirectly modifies the global `var` variable, but it doesn't work. Is there a way to get an `assigns` clause for the local `p` variable or the location return from `a()`? Here is the code:

```
int var;
//@ assigns \nothing;
int *a(){
    return &var;
}
//@ assigns *p;
void b(int* p){
  *p = 1;
}
//@ assigns \nothing;
void foo(){
   int *p = a();
   b(p);
}
//@ assigns var;
void main(){
    var = 0;
    foo();
    return;
}
```

frama-c command:

`frama-c -wp test.c`

```
[kernel] Parsing test.c (with preprocessing)
[wp] Warning: Missing RTE guards
[wp] 10 goals scheduled
[wp] [Alt-Ergo] Goal typed_foo_assign_normal_part3 : Unknown (103ms)
[wp] [Alt-Ergo] Goal typed_foo_assign_exit_part3 : Unknown (Qed:4ms) (102ms)
[wp] Proved goals:    8 / 10
  Qed:             8 
  Alt-Ergo:        0  (unknown: 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed, `foo` *does* assign something, and `assigns \nothing` is an invalid clause for this function. The proper clause is indeed `assigns var`. Within an `assigns` clause, you must list all global variables that are modified, plus all the variables that are local to a caller and that can be reference through a formal.

Now, why does the proof of the variants with `assigns var` not go through? Well, as written, in `foo`, WP cannot guess where `p` points to, as it has no way of knowing that it is actually equal to `&a`. You must add this information to the specification of function `a`. With this modification, the proof is immediate.

Full code:

```
int var;

/*@ assigns \nothing;
    ensures \result == &var; */
int *a(){
    return &var;
}

//@ assigns *p;
void b(int* p){
  *p = 1;
}

//@ assigns var;
void foo(){
   int *p = a();
   b(p);
}

//@ assigns var;
void main(){
    var = 0;
    foo();
    return;
}
```

Comment: It works.  I'm still wondering if there is a way to come up with the assigns clause based on `a()` post conditions?  For example, what happen if I don't have exposure to global variable `var` within the test.c source file.

Comment: If `a` allocates, then the result of the call must either be de-allocated by `foo` (otherwise you would have a leak), or returned/stored into a variable accessible by the caller of `foo`. In this case, assuming that this variable is `v`, you can write `assigns \at(Post,*v)`. This is slightly unwieldy, though.
The alternative is to store the result of `a` in a ghost variable.